# Table column alignment

Tags: tables, siunitx

I just cannot get the third column alignment right, does anyone know how, please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
  \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l S[table-format=-1.2(2)] S[table-format=-1.1e1]}   
\toprule
 {\textbf{Res.}}    & {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$}    & {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$}    \\
\midrule
4           & -0.60(14)         & 1738 \\
5           & -0.39(11)     & 1348\\
6           & -0.32(10)     & 612 \\
7           & -0.54(17)     & 1159  \\
8a          & -0.36(10)     & 621  \\
9           & -0.50(14)     & 800  \\
10          & -0.26(14)     & 544  \\
11a         & -0.54(16)     & -1140  \\
11b         & -0.50(15)     & 867  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[]{}
\end{table}
```

Comment: If your numbers do not have a floating value why do you use `-1.1e1`?

Comment: I actually dont know, I do not really understand how format tables with siunitx.  However, does it affect the third column alignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain the formatting of numbers with `siunitx` from your code:

`table-format=-1.1e1` means it uses scientific notation (the `e` is for `exponent`), with a mantissa having possibly a `—` sign, `1 digit` before the decimal dot (`1.`), and `1 digit` after the decimal dot (`.1`). The exponent use `1 digit` (that's the `e1` part of the format).

`table-format=-1.2(2)` does not use scientific notation, but has an `uncertainty part` which uses `2 digits`.

Thus for your last column, you should have

`table-format=-4.0` (four digits with possibly a — sign, and no decimal part).

Comment: What about if my last column is a mix of words and number. Example : for the first row:Inf and the rest rows: 3X10^6?

Comment: For cell contents not fitting the format, you get it centred putting it within a pair of braces.

Comment: This is the new code, where should I change?  \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l S[table-format=-1.2(2)] S[table-format=-4]} 
\toprule
 {\textbf{Res.}}    & {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$}    & {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$}    \\
\midrule
1  & -0.61(17)  & Inf. \\
2  & -0.60(17)  & Inf. \\
3  & -0.59(18)  & 3$\times$10$^6$\\ 
4 & -0.56(20)  & Inf. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[]{}
 \label{}
\end{table}

Answer (score 1):

Change `S[table-format=-1.1e1]` to `S[table-format=-4.0]`. `-4.0` means: "Set aside enough space for four-digit numbers prefaced by a `-` symbol, and don't set aside any space for digits *after* the decimal marker" (since we're dealing with whole numbers). *Why* set `-4.0`? It's because the largest number in the third column (in absolute value terms) is "-1140".

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bm,siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l 
                S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
                S[table-format=-4.0] }   
\toprule
{\textbf{Res.}} & {$\bm{\beta}$} & {$\bm{\chi^{2}}$}  \\
\midrule
4           & -0.60(14)     & 1738 \\
5           & -0.39(11)     & 1348\\
6           & -0.32(10)     & 612 \\
7           & -0.54(17)     & 1159  \\
8a          & -0.36(10)     & 621  \\
9           & -0.50(14)     & 800  \\
10          & -0.26(14)     & 544  \\
11a         & -0.54(16)     & -1140  \\
11b         & -0.50(15)     & 867  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[]{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```